# Reduce the following set to obtain basis of real vector space $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Reduce the set $\beta = \{2i-1,2i+3,4 \} $ to obtain basis of real vector space $\mathbb{C}$

What I know:

In order to be basis of a vector space, the set under consideration must be linearly independent and spans real vector space $\mathbb{C}$.

Clearly the set $\beta = \{2i-1,2i+3,4 \} $ is not linearly independent so we have to reduce it. But how?

Can someone please suggest anything. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: The dimension of the real vector space $\mathbb C$ is two (because the set $\{1, i\}$ forms a somewhat "canonical" basis). Therefore each basis has exactly two elements...
Taking one of the three elements away might already help... You just have to check if the remaining two are linearly independent

Comment: @Lukas Okay thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Bbb{C}$ be the vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ and $\beta = \{2i-1,2i+3,4\}$. We want to obtain a basis of $\Bbb{C}$ from the set $\beta$. First, note that the canonical basis of $\Bbb{C}$ is $(1,i)$ (because $\Bbb{C}$ is over the field $\Bbb{R}$). So, $\dim{\Bbb{C}} = 2$, what means that any basis of this vector space must have exactly two elements.

Now, let’s look at the set $\beta$. It is straightforward to see that $\beta$ is linearly dependent because
\begin{align*}
2i + 3 = (2i-1) + 4.
\end{align*}

Hence, $\langle \beta \rangle = \langle \{2i-1,4\} \rangle$. To see if $\{2i-4,4\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb{C}$ all you have to do is to check if the set is linearly independent. I believe that you are able to check this by yourself.

After this, you will conclude that the set is linearly independent, so the $\dim{\langle \{2i-1,4\} \rangle} = 2$. But, since $\dim{\Bbb{C}} = 2$, we have that $\langle \{2i-1,4\} \rangle = \Bbb{C}$. Therefore, you get a basis $(2i-1,4)$ of $\Bbb{C}$ from $\beta$.